# Jquery toggle form on button click

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button, toggle

I want to show a form only when a button is pressed. This works fine.
When I click the button again I want form to dissapear. Can someone explain what the problem is?
Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#instantchannel').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.
 var numclicks = 2
  $('#instant').click(function() {
  if(numclicks%2==1){
  numclicks=++;
   $('#instantchannel').show();//Form shows on button click
}else{
numclicks=++;
 $('#instantchannel').hide();//Form shows on button click
}
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: you've it in you title, `$('#instant').click(function() {$('#instantchannel').toggle();});`

Comment: Just use [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Comment: show the html mark-up

Comment: @NikolaMitev - Why do you need it? What would it add over what there is in the script?

Comment: `numclicks=++;` yuck.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method for just these cases:

```
$('#instant').click(function() {
  $('#instantchannel').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Another option with Javascript and CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `;` after `var numclicks = 2`. Also, `numclicks` is no longer visible when you click the button. And, you should use `toggle()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#instantchannel').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.
  $('#instant').click(function() {
    $('#instantchannel').toggle();//Form toggles on button click
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to count the number of clicks. Just use the [.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#instantchannel').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.
 $('#instant').click(function() {
  $('#instantchannel').toggle();
 });

});
</script>
```

Yet, if you want to know the problem in you code, you are missing a `;` after `var numclicks = 2` and the correct usage `++` operator is `numclicks++;`.

Comment: I currently have this as my script '<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#instantchannel').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.

  $('#instant').click(function() {
   $('#instantchannel').toggle();//Form shows on button click

     $('#play').click(function() {
   $('#instantchannel').toggle();//Form shows on button click
   
   });
 });
 </script>' however the toggle isn't working. the form appears instead of being hidden and doesn't toggle. i did get it to work my original way though, but i'd like to figure out how do it correctly with toggle